# ASP.NET Webservice - Trace slows process when remotely called

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

We have a webservice which was running fine until recently.

When called locally the everything works fine, but when called remotely it takes up to 30sec to get the response. Not only for the the webmethod calls but also for plain calls to the asmx or for the wsdl.

The trace shows a gap between the return from GetHandler and the call to ProcessRequest.
Do you have any ideas of what could cause the issue at that point (only for remote calls) ?

Here is an extract of the service log showing the time gap when making a get to the .asmx from a browser :

```
System.Web.Services.Asmx Information: 0 : Return from IHttpHandlerFactory.GetHandler
Caller: System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory#23522948::GetHandler()
ProcessId=6420
LogicalOperationStack=
ThreadId=7
DateTime=2013-09-23T14:35:36.3381748Z
Timestamp=3850992018156

System.Web.Services.Asmx Information: 0 : Calling IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
Caller: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SyncSessionlessHandler#41622463::ProcessRequest()
Request Host Address: **.**.**.**
Request Host Name: ***
Request Url: [GET] http://***/***.asmx
ProcessId=6420
LogicalOperationStack=
ThreadId=7
DateTime=2013-09-23T14:35:48.3970521Z
Timestamp=3851164660296

System.Web.Services.Asmx Information: 0 : Calling Void Documentation()
Method: System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol#31364015::Documentation()
Caller: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SyncSessionlessHandler#41622463::Invoke()
ProcessId=6420
LogicalOperationStack=
ThreadId=7
DateTime=2013-09-23T14:35:48.3970521Z
Timestamp=3851164663918
```

Thank you

**EDIT**

After comparing the webservice with another one we have I finally found the origin of the problem : It was the trace itself. Once disabled evrything worked fine remotely.

I understand that tracing take time, but 30sec seems a lot and why would it take more time only for remote calls ?
As explain in the comment there is no authentication set up and the pool user has sufficiemt right since trace is actually written. Any ideas ?

Here is the trace setting

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <trace autoflush="true" />
       <sources>
           <source name="System.Web.Services.Asmx">
               <listeners>
                   <add name="AsmxTraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\local.log" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId" />
               </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="System.Web.Services.Asmx" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Have you configured any security for the web service? Generally that slows up the web request a bit.

Comment: Nope, authentication is set to none in the web.config and in IIS only Anonymous authentication is enabled.

Comment: Try using dyna trace or similar applications to get a complete detailed trace of your .net code.. might be insightful.